# "Create new table" is not visible on SSMS 2016 for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, ssms, ssms-2016

I have a shared hosting. I was happy with it. I was creating new databases on its panel and then I was managing my databases with SQL Server Management Studio. I could add new table by right clicking the database with designer.

Database is: SQL Server 10.0.2531    (SQL Server 2008 SP1 I think)

My SSMS details

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio          13.0.15500.91
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools        13.0.1605.86
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)         10.0.10586.0
Microsoft MSXML                                 3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.10586.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                6.3.10586
```

I have updated my SSMS to 2016. But now, when I right click on my database, there is no "New -> Table  menu". The right-click menu is only "Filter, Start Powershell, Report and Refresh"

Now I can create new table by New Query menu (by writing query), but where is my "New -> Table  menu"? Is this a security issue ?

Comment: I think that it is just that SQL Server 2008 is too old, so not supported by SSMS 2016

Comment: but why that is not written anywhere?

Comment: Yes I was searching for a reference before posting as an answer. It comes down to supported versions of software. Ssms does support a few back releases but they don't support them all. You have to draw a line in the sand somewhere. 2014, 2012 I would expect support for but beyond that...?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4062/new-sql-server-management-studio-azure-integration/

Comment: According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) it is supported: "This version of SSMS works with all supported versions of SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 - SQL Server 2016), and provides ..."

Comment: It is missing for me on a brand new table created in a brand new install of SSMS-2016 for a brand new instance of SSExpress-2016. I vaguely remember permissions/roles having to be explicitly set but I cannot quite recall the exact steps.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:  in Microsoft speak they probably are referring to  "Mainstream Support End Date", that would make SQL 2012 the earliest supported version

Comment: @SamusArin OneNiceFriend was able to create a table via script, so it wasn't a permissions issue in that case

Comment: @Mike - the text I quoted says, **specifically** SQL Server 2008. The next line (not quoted) also says it should work for 2000 and 2005 but some features may not work.

Comment: What is the compatibility level of the database?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug reported for this issue

[connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2883440)

[social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/346a5a23-1f60-4c6d-ab98-3805edba1016/where-is-design-table-in-ssms-2016-july-release?forum=sqltools)

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS you can use a SQL script to create a new table because that processing is done on the server. However, SSMS provides the capability to add a table, here the User interface has to be developed to provide the necessary features for each version of SQL Server, this obviously has an overhead. So gradually older versions get dropped.

SSMS for SQL 2012 did not provide support for SQL Server 2005.

Now as Damien_The_Unbeliever points out SSMS for SQL Server 2016 supports all supported versions of SQL Server. But this is for  "Mainstream Support End Date", so alas, SQL Server 2012 is the last version that has full UI support.

Still you can have mulitple versions of SSMS installed, just like you may need to  keep BIDS as well as Data Tools installed to maintain older verions of SSIS