# Where is New Table in SQL Server 2016 Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2016

I just installed the July 2016 update of SSMS, and there is no `New Table` menu item when I right-click on **Tables**.

Did it disappear?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4062/new-sql-server-management-studio-azure-integration/

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl That links says nothing about missing context menu items for creating a table

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you working with? If it's Express, I don't think SSMS 2016 supports all the same features for the server editions vs express edition. +New table is one of them. There are others like Stretch Database even though the feature is available on express edition. If you are using Express edition, suggest filing a bug on https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback

Comment: @SQLmojoe Well the option was there before the July 2016 update. It's the SSMS released in June (version 13.0.15000.23). Now after the update, the option (and others) is gone

Comment: I just tried it on my SSMS July 2016 and got a "New Table" option. It was under "New" then "Table" was in a submenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem.
Probably there is a bug in SSMS16

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38219386/2470789

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2883440