# SQL Server 2016 Management Studio : no "New Table" option

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2016 Express edition. Everything seems to work fine except there's no "New Table" option to create a table (Image). There are 2 empty folders, System and File tables. Any ideas what is missing or what is being done wrong? Right-clicking on File Tables does not show a New Table option to create one

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Create new table" is not visible on SSMS 2016 for SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195071/create-new-table-is-not-visible-on-ssms-2016-for-sql-server-2008)

Comment: In my case there is no older version of SQL Server. I installed SSMS 2016 for SQL Express 2016 for the first time. There must be a bug. I might have to restore Windows to an earlier version and install SQL Express 2014.

Comment: If this is the July release it may be a bug

Comment: Yes it is the latest downloaded July 8.

Comment: Based on the screenshot... you need to right click on `Tables`, not `FileTables`.... unless you want to create a file table?

Comment: I should have made the screenshot right-clicking on Tables, it gives exactly the same result you see for the FileTables. No "New Table" in either case.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a known issue reported on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2883440) where some of the SSMS Object Explorer context menu items are unavailable in the SSMS July 2016 Update when connected to a SQL Server Express or LocalDb edition.  As Microsoft noted in the Connect comments, a fix is planned for the July update.  An interim workaround is to uninstall the current July 2016 update and install the [previous June 2016 Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238488.aspx) instead.  Alternatively, one could use Developer Edition instead of Express or LocalDb.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have also experienced with 2 different computers in 2 different locations connection problems when files are being downloaded to be installed. The installation of Express 2016 is suddenly aborted with a "Ooops.." message about connection problem. It is quite frustrating and a waste of time.

Comment: I installed "SSMS SQL Server Management Studio 17.5" and I was able to see the other tables option. (Table...) It was not working with SSMS 2016.