# Unable to create new table in SQL Server 2016 Mgmt Studio

Tags: sql-server, create-table

I am trying to create a new table in SQL Server 2016 Management Studio.

I am following the instructions provided on this [website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188264.aspx#SSMSProcedure).

There is a line that states, `In Object Explorer, right-click the Tables node of your database and then click New Table.`

Somehow I don't see this option (`NewTable`) when I right click on the Tables node.

Not sure where I am wrong. Any advice is much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have both MySQL and SqlServer tags, which is it?

Comment: @RBarryYoung ah its MicrosoftSQL Server 2016

Comment: Does the CREATE TABLE command work?  Ex: CREATE TABLE FOO(BAR INT);

Comment: Based on the picture i suspect either 1) you do not have privs to create tables, or 2) you are using the SQL Express client interface which does not have all functionality.  Use the CREATE TABLE command above to test (1).

Comment: @RBarryYoung, `create table FOO(BAR INT)` worked

Comment: What's the product info (edition, version) of your Management Studio?  It should be in the Help..About somewhere.

Comment: @RBarryYoung,  SQL Server 2016 Management Studio                                                                                 `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      13.0.15500.91`

Comment: Can you show an image of the dialog window?

Comment: Ok, looks like a bug.  See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195071/create-new-table-is-not-visible-on-ssms-2016-for-sql-server-2008.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, uh Microsoft, did not release any patch yet, i guess i should use the 2012 version now. Thanks Barry.

Comment: This is the July version.  Connect says that you can rollback to the June version to fix it.